# Grabbing data from first column of table and appending to last column in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to grab a product number which is in the first column of this table, and create a last column to append this product number in a link. Each number has a PDF file of the same name.

Essentially I want to grab the first `<td>` value in a row, and append another `<td>` with that value to the end of that row.

I can append the table row with static icons and links, but I cannot figure out how to make each row display the product number that is in the first td of that same row.

```
$('#table tbody').each(function() {
    var $partNumber = $('tr:not(.row0) td.column0').html(); 
    $('tr:not(.row0)').append('<td><a class="button button-inverse button-block button-small" href="/writable/data-sheets/' + $partNumber + '.pdf"><i class="fal fa-file"></i></a></td>')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in general a jquery object represents any number of HTML elements. The `each` method iterates over those elements. (Not their children.) I assume there's only one `id="table"` element, and it only contains one `<tbody>`, so your loop only runs once.

When the loop runs, `$('tr:not(.row0) td.column0')` is a jquery object, which contains several HTML elements, namely the first `<td>` in each row except for the first row. Also, it's not localised to `$('#table tbody')`, so if there's another table somewhere with `td.column0` elements it will pick up those too. But anyway... `$partNumber` will be the inner HTML of the first element in the jquery object, which is the first cell in the second row.

Then, the next line will generate a jquery object appending (a copy of) the new element to the end of every row. Note that these new cells will be exact copies of each other, since they all use the same value of `$partNumber`.

So, if my analysis is correct, your code adds a new column in the correct place, but all the links are to the href that the first row is supposed to link to. Is this what you're seeing?

To fix this: Firstly, you want to iterate over the rows, not the table bodies. Then, inside your anonymous function, you need to get the row you're currently on. [The documentation for `each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) says this can be done using arguments to the function.* So if you change it to `function(n, element)`, `element` will represent the `<tr>` element. That's not a jquery object, but you can get a jquery object with `$(element)`. From there you can get the first `<td>` inside it using the `find` method. And the rest is as you've done it.

In summary:

```
$('#table tbody tr:not(.row0)').each(function(n, element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var $partNumber = $element.find('td.column0').html(); 
    $element.append('<td><a class="button button-inverse button-block button-small" href="/writable/data-sheets/' + $partNumber + '.pdf"><i class="fal fa-file"></i></a></td>')
});
```

* You can also do it using `this`; the syntax is slightly shorter, but personally I don't like the idea of `this` in javascript. But it's up to you.

Comment: This is one of the best explanations ever for a newbie at jQuery and Javascript. I thank you for explaining it to me so eloquently. Two follow-up questions: What does the `n` represent as the first arguement? And `element` only equals the element being selected (which is the `tr:not(.row)` selector)?

Comment: (1) See the link above. `n` is the index within the list, i.e. 0 on the first iteration, 1 on the second, etc. It's not used here, but if you write `function(element)` then `element` will be the index, not the HTML element. But as mentioned in the footnote, you could instead do `function() { var $element = $(this); ...`.

Comment: (2) Yes, `element` is just a single element which matches the selector `tr:not(.row)`. It's not a jquery object, it's a raw HTML element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement or something like that. These things are the original method of interaction between the HTML and the javascript. They're still there, under the hood, but jquery and other frameworks have been built on top so you rarely have to look at them. They're quite unwieldy to use.